# I want to break a wall with a ball in real life

Tags: texturing

I am new to visual effects and to blender, of course. So I would appreciate it if anyone could help me.
So basically I recorded myself throwing a ball to a wall. When the ball hits the wall I want the wall to break off(fall off).
Here is a gif!
[image]

I was able to motion track the video and created an object to where the wall should be in 3D space.
[image]

Now my problem is I don't know how to make the object look like the wall.
I don't know how to make its texture look like the texture on the wall and then drop off.
Can anyone help me?